# SQL: How to get list pairs of table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Requirement: List the customer pairs who frequent the same bar (i.e., list all the pairs of customer who might meet in a coffee bar)

Bar table:

```
-------------------------
id| name                 
-------------------------
1 | Vivamus nibh         
2 | odio tristique       
3 | vulputate ullamcorper
4 | Cras lorem           
5 | libero est,
```

Customer Table:

```
-----------------------
id| name              
-----------------------
1 | Warren    
2 | Olympia            
3 | Logan
4 | Summer
5 | Kamal
6 | Fernandez
```

Frequents Table:

```
-----------------
cust_id | bar_id
-----------------
1       | 1
2       | 1
3       | 2
4       | 2
5       | 3
6       | 4
```

Output expected:

```
---------------------------------------
customer1 | customer2 | barname
---------------------------------------
Warren    |  Olympia  | Vivamus nibh
Logan     |  Summer   | odio tristique
```

Here is my try, but it didn't work:

```
select c1.name, c2.name, b1.name, b2.name
from frequents f1, frequents f2
join bar b1 on f1.bar_id = b1.id
join bar b2 on f2.bar_id = b2.id
join customer c1 on f1.cust_id = c1.id
join customer c2 on f2.cust_id = c2.id
where f1.bar_id = f2.bar_id;
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: It is not clear what a pair is here, like the previous comment point out we need sample data and expected result

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for reminding me. I've edited.

Comment: @PhuongThuan both the requirements look similar. If they are different, you need to highlight the difference with two different expected outputs. Also, your sample data is **not enough**, as it should contain some customers which may not pair. Currently, all the customers and bar are making a possible pair in expected output.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I've edited. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could join the bar table with the frequent table, twice, and then continue joining to get the customers name. In order to prevent duplicates, you could take an arbitrary decision that one `cust_id` should be smaller than the other:

```
SELECT b.name, c1.name, c2.name
FROM   bar b
JOIN   frequents f1 ON f1.bar_id = b.id
JOIN   frequents f2 ON f2.bar_id = b.id AND f1.cust_id < f2.cust_id
JOIN   customer  c1 ON c1.id = f1.cust_id
JOIN   customer  c2 ON c2.id = f2.cust_id
```

**[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uzjEpFePVSKwqGnN215yUu/0)**

Answer (score 1):

I am using a sub query to join on frequents with same bar but different customer and also making use of "sorting" customer id by using > to avoid duplicates

```
SELECT c1.name customer1, f2.name customer2, b.name barname
FROM frequents f
JOIN customer c1 ON c1.id = f.cust_id
JOIN bar b ON f.bar_id = b.id
JOIN (SELECT cust_id, bar_id, name
      FROM frequents 
      JOIN customer ON id = cust_id) AS f2 ON f2.bar_id = f.bar_id AND f2.cust_id > f.cust_id
```

**DB Fiddle**: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/npYnEgJAdH4yPa6NqBiqoT/1

Answer (score 0):

To get all pairs per bar, self-joining the Frequents table can get you that.

Then you can just join the other tables on their ID to get the names.

```
SELECT 
cust1.name AS customer1, 
cust2.name AS customer2, 
bar.name AS barname
FROM frequents freq1
JOIN frequents freq2 ON (freq2.bar_id = freq1.bar_id AND freq2.cust_id > freq1.cust_id)
JOIN bar ON bar.id = freq1.bar_id
LEFT JOIN customer cust1 ON cust1.id = freq1.cust_id
LEFT JOIN customer cust2 ON cust2.id = freq2.cust_id
ORDER BY freq1.cust_id, freq2.cust_id, freq1.bar_id;
```

*SqlFiddle test* [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e562b/2/0)